# How to get Powershell to run SH scripts

Tags: powershell, scripting, environment-variables, sh

Can someone please tell me how I get Powershell to run .sh scripts? It keeps just trying to open the file i need in Notepad when I run this command:

```
.\update-version.sh 123
```

I've added .SH to my PATHEXT environment variable and also added the Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 directory to the Path environment variable.

Comment: .sh is for linux systems isn't it ? don't you use cygwin to run these scripts ?

Comment: please post a few lines of the script-code from update-version.sh

Comment: Thanks, got it working using cygwin

Comment: This is a really valid question these days, when it wasn't 9 years ago. With Powershell 7, most of the usual middle-of-the-road *nix isms work pefectly. cp, mkdir -p, even directories like ~, even back and forward slashes, are valid in powershell. I run across a lot of .sh files that would run fine in powershell, but don't know how to associate it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell scripts have a .ps1 extension (along with other supported extensions such as psm1,psd1 etc) it will not run other extensions other than that.

Answer (score 1):

I had also got the same issue when i am trying to run `.sh` files. The solution is you need to enable bash shell by typing `bash`.
After enabling Bash on Windows, you can run `.sh` files by typing `bash ./fileName.sh`. 
 But i have tried through git bash with typing `. fileName.sh` it worked well. 
These are the two solutions that I have found, and you can try whatever you wish.